# How to pass a variable from a shell script to a python script and save it then

Tags: python, django, shell

I want to ask you guys how to pass a variable from a shell script to a python script and save it then as local variable. I have a Variable in the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
userpem=$(egrep "CN=$1/" index.txt|awk '{print $3}').pem
output='openssl x509 -in $userpem -noout -text'
export output
```

I read on some posts that I can do that with `os.environ(foo)` but I just saw examples like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os
import subprocess
from django.http import HttpResponse


def info(request, benutzername):
  os.chdir("/var/www/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/2.0/keys")
  subprocess.Popen(["/var/www/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/getinfo.sh",benutzername])
  output = os.environ['output']
  return HttpResponse(output)
```

Comment: `var = os.getenv('variablename')` or `var = os.environ['variablename']`

Comment: If you don't want to print it, what _do_ you want to do with it? Stick it in a global or local variable? (@hus787's comment shows how to do that.) Save it to a file? Turn the bits into PCM audio and play it through the sound card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what your trying to do.

fedorqui's answer shows how to read environment variables from Python, but that won't help you.

---

First, you're just starting the shell script and immediately assuming it's already done its work, when it may not even have finished launching yet. You might get lucky and have it work sometimes, but not reliably. You need to [`wait`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) for the `Popen` object (which also means you need to store it in a variable)—or, even more simply, [`call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) it (which waits until it finishes) instead of just kicking it off.

---

And you probably want to check the return value, or just use [`check_call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call), so you'll know if it fails.

---

Meanwhile, if you fix that, it still won't do you any good. `export` doesn't export variables to your parent process, it exports them to your *children*.

If you want to pass a value back to your parent, the simplest way to do that is by writing it to `stdout`. Then, of course, your Python code will have to read your output. The easiest way to do that is to use [`check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `check_call`.

---

Finally, I'm pretty sure you wanted to actually run `openssl` and capture its output, not just set `output` to the literal string `openssl x509 -in $userpem -noout -text`. (Especially not with single quotes, which will prevent `$userpem` from being substituted, meaning you looked it up for nothing.) To do that, you need to use backticks or `$()`, as you did in the previous line, not quotes.

---

So:

```
#!/bin/bash
userpem=$(egrep "CN=$1/" index.txt|awk '{print $3}').pem
output=$(openssl x509 -in $userpem -noout -text)
echo $output
```

And:

```
def info(request, benutzername):
    os.chdir("/var/www/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/2.0/keys")
    output = subprocess.check_output(["/var/www/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/getinfo.sh",benutzername])
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

---

As a side note, `os.chdir` is usually a bad idea in web servers. That will set the current directory for all requests, not just this one. (It's especially bad if you're using a semi-preemptive greenlet server framework, like something based on `gevent`, because a different request could `chdir` you somewhere else between your `chdir` call and your `subprocess` call…)

Comment: omg ! all that worked out !!! well it seems like I have to learn much more ^^ I thank you very much for that good explanation as well !!! that check_output so awesome :D and thanks for note with the os.chdir problems :) pretty awesome you took so much time to explain that :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `os.environ['variablename']` to work with an environment variable.

For example here the `v` variable is created and exported:

```
$ export v="hello"
```

Let's create a script `a.py`:

```
import os

d=os.environ['v']
print "my environment var v is --> " + d
```

And calling it:

```
$ python a.py
my environment var v is --> hello
```

Comment: Updated using it as local variable, as the OP indicates on comments.

Comment: I tried what you did as well d=os.environ['v'], probably should have written it :/ it just gives me following: Exception Type:  KeyError
Exception Value: 'v'

Comment: @Newbie can you post everything you tried? It is not clear what you want to accomplish. Also, note a variable declared in a script might just be accessible from that subshell, so when the program finishes you cannot access to it any more.

Comment: @Newbie ok :) And how do you call it? You call the shell script and then python script?

Comment: @Newbie: Exporting a variable doesn't affect the _parent process's_ environment, it only affects _child processes'_ environments.

Comment: @fedorqui  Edit: or maybe I did not save the output of the command properly... because when I echo this shit it gives me some kidn of error and when I don't use a variable I can see the output in the shell ^^ 
well I call the python script first, then it changes in the directory where the shell script is at, passes the variable "benutzername" (in the shell script it is $1) which I got from my webservice. Well and then the shell script does what it has to do and it works good but it doesn't export the variable properly or python doesn't receive it properly :/

Comment: @Newbie to use a variable from a shell script, you have to `source` it. This way it will be accessible to you. If you just `export`, it will not.

Comment: @fedorqui: But a Python script can't `source` a sh script. That's basically the `sh` equivalent of Python's `from foo import *`. I think what he's trying to do is basically impossible, so he needs a different way to accomplish his actual goal.